# Problema con la compatibilidad de la propiedad backdrop-filter de css en firefox

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema y es que hice un header con transparencia y le di un blur con bakdrop filter para que lo del fondo se vea borroso lo probé en Google y en Edge  y funciona perfectamente pero en Firefox no, osea no se aplica el blur solo la transparencia del color rgba que le di. quisiera saber como hacer par que en firefox sea compatible esa propiedad de css.

Aqui les dejo el codigo de Css.

```css
.header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(2rem);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(2rem);
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

La propiedad `backdrop-filter` está implementado en el navegador Firefox para escritorio a partir de la versión 70.0 pero no está activado por defecto, si quieres probarlo en tu navegador Firefox debes activar algunas preferencias.

Paso 1

Ir a tu navegador Firefox y poner en tu barra de buscador "about:config" para ir a la configuración.

Paso 2

- En el buscador de configuración, buscas la preferencia llamada "layout.css.backdrop-filter.enabled" y la activas.
- Buscas la preferencia llamada "gfx.webrender.all" y la activas.
- Cierras el navegador y lo vuelves abrir.

Fuente: [backdrop-filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter)

Comment: Pero al agregar la propiedad filter en google se ve muy borroso de echo ya no se ve nada las  letras del menu de navegacion, ni el logo ni nada

Comment: Actualice la respuesta, si los pasos no se comprenden muy bien me lo indicas para mejorarlo, lo probé en mi navegador Firefox cambiando la configuración y me funcionó, espero ayudar y aportar algo.

Comment: claro que si funciona pero como aria para que cuando cualquier usuario que abra la pagina ya se active esa configuración de Firefox, porque la pagina se va a publicar y para los que tengan firefox sin habilitado esa configuracion no se va a ver bien el header; nose como se aria talvez con javascript.? O como.

Comment: Lo que quiero esque cualquier usuario que lo abra con firefox vea bien los estilos que tengo.

Comment: @DanielAlvarez Queria preguntarte como lo haz resuelto ?  Jjajssaj. Estoy usando el back drop para aplicar un blur al fondo, en chrome y Opera se ve bien, pero lo pruebo en un navegador distinto como Libre Wolf y no se ve el blur (Libre Wolf sale de FireFox) no se si hay otra alternativa para esto